# How to get reg strValue from HKCU using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I'm attempting to use VBScript to return the EXE path of a specific application by reading the Windows Registry and returning the value as a variable for later use but for some reason my script will not return the requested value. I have verified that the value and location specified do in fact exist in the registry but am still unable to return the required value. If it helps... I'm developing this on Win 7 64bit.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."

Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\MyPath"
strValueName = "ExePath"
oReg.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
Set ExePath = strValue
StdOut.WriteLine "ExePath = " & strValue
```

The listed code returns an error: Object required: 'strValue' with Code: 800A01A8

If you have any ideas, please feel free to share, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove "Set" from

Set Exepath = strValue

That's all. It thinks you're trying to create an object, when really you're just assigning a string value to a new variable.